# Terrain tools not supported Unity 2020.2 Alpha?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Lately I've been working on a big game, using the HDRP. It looks so good, but the terrain itself, does not. Not at all. I tried importing the terrain tools, but I couldn't find them in the package manager, even with preview packages enabled...
I also went to the online aasset store, but found nothing else than the previews package, with only previews, no tools at all.
Does this mean terrain tools is unsupported in my Unity version, or has something else happened? Anyways, it would be nice with some help getting the terrain tools to work in my game.

Thanks in advance, Loaf :D

Comment: `I've been working on a big game` ... then you shouldn't even think bout using an **ALPHA** or **BETA** version! They are full of bugs and not stable for production ... stick to the latest stable version! Btw `2019.4 LTS` is now out and should be your choice for the next year or so ;)

Comment: As far as I know, there are no plans for removing terrain tools, so it might be an issue with the alpha. I'm 100% in with the previous comment, don't use an alpha version for a big project!, I wouldn't even use 2020 unless it were necessary. If you're aiming for a long term project,  LTSs are meant for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution my dudes! Someone helped me on the official discord explaining how they would fix this problem later.
All you need to do is to write: "com.unity.terrain-tools": "3.0.1-preview" in your package manifest.

No problem :D

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to open your package manager window, click on the "+" button in the top left corner and click on "Add package by name". There paste this -> "com.unity.terrain-tools".
This will install the latest terrain tools package available.
The package name above can be found from unity documentation; for example for this package the documentation can be found at "https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/com.unity.terrain-tools.html" and the package name I used is written right below the title "Terrain Tools". So this method can be used to install any missing/additional packages.